# what is the significance of " #!flask/bin/python " in flask?

Tags: python, flask

why this line `#!flask/bin/python` is added on the top of this code?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I got following error when I removed it

```
from: can't read /var/mail/flask
./app.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./app.py: line 3: `app = Flask(__name__)'
```

Comment: I can't see that line in the code posted.

Comment: It’s a shebang, and it tells the shell that when you invoke this file as `./app.py`, it should be run with the Python interpreter at flask/bin/python. Since it’s missing, it tries to run the file with the default shell (which is probably bash, and which will choke on a .py file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#!` is a `shebang`. On UNIX/UNIX like operating systems it basically tells your shell which executable (python in your case) to execute the script with. Without it, the shell is executing the script directly and since it does not understand Python code, it raises an error.