# Basic Flask: ImportError: cannot import name Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm following along with a [Flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world), and I'm creating a `run.py` file, running chmod a+x run.py, and running the file as `./run.py`.

Unfortunately, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/microblog/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

For reference, my run.py file is:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

And when I run

```
from flask import Flask
```

there's no issue (I don't get any error message).

I looked at similar issues on SO and it looks like often it was having a file called `flask.py` but I don't have one (AFAIK).

Any idea what I did incorrectly?

Comment: Near duplicate of [what is the significance of “ #!flask/bin/python ” in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954599/what-is-the-significance-of-flask-bin-python-in-flask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and run again. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script).

Comment: also [what is the significance of “ #!flask/bin/python ” in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954599/what-is-the-significance-of-flask-bin-python-in-flask)